# Is anyone else having a problem with Youtubes Api while trying to get live users?

Tags: api, youtube-api, google-apis-explorer

Checking for live users with youtube's API isn't working for me.

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=*****&key=*****&type=video&eventType=live

removing channelId or eventType works but that's not what im looking for, could 
this youtubes side or something?

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely something going on with the YouTube Data API. If you give it a try on the on the Deverloper Console for [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) it won't work if you are providing `channelId`. However, if you provide `channelId` it will always return 0 results.

[Google's instructions for getting help](https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/support) say to add the tag `google-apis-explorer` to your post. If you can edit that, give it a try. Hopefully we'll all get some answers soon.